# How to build json object using POJO class using subset of fields in it

Tags: rest-assured

I need to build a JSON object using a POJO class ,but need to build it using subset of fields at times and all fields at times. please let me know how to handle this in RestAssured.

Comment: Please provide a reproducable example.

Comment: I need to build a JSON with same name but different combination of fields, Say my POJO calss have fields A,B,C,D and i need to build one JSON using {A,C,D} and other using {C,D}..etc

Answer (score 0):

Jackson annotation [@JsonInclude](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html) can help you to achieve that. For example:

```java
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
static class User {
    private String name;
    private String bio;
}


@Test
void name3() {
    User user1 = new User();
    user1.setName("lucas");
    RestAssured.given().log().body()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(user1)
            .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");

    User user2 = new User();
    user2.setBio("nothing");
    RestAssured.given().log().body()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(user2)
            .post("https://postman-echo.com/post");
}
```

Log:

```
Body:
{
    "name": "lucas"
}
Body:
{
    "bio": "nothing"
}
```